# UTF-8 bytes to string

Tags: elisp

I'm trying to convert a list like `'(110 111 101 204 136 108)` to a string like `"noël"`.

I tried using `(mapcar (lambda (c) (decode-char 'unicode c)) '(110 111 101 204 136 108))`, but it resulted in `(110 111 101 204 136 108)`, the same as the input. (Also, I recognize that there's no way to decode a Unicode character from a single byte of UTF-8, so that's definitely the wrong function.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few options...

```el
(with-temp-buffer
  (set-buffer-multibyte nil)
  (apply #'insert '(110 111 101 204 136 108))
  (decode-coding-region (point-min) (point-max) 'utf-8 t))
```

or:

```el
(decode-coding-string
 (mapconcat #'byte-to-string '(110 111 101 204 136 108) "")
 'utf-8)
```

or more directly:

```el
(string-as-multibyte
  (apply #'unibyte-string '(110 111 101 204 136 108)))
```